# How to get the data from a download url with matlab?

Tags: matlab, web-scraping, url

I have the next URL: https://www.banxico.org.mx/SieInternet/consultarDirectorioInternetAction.do?accion=consultarSeries&locale=es&version=3&anoInicial=1996&anoFinal=2099&tipoInformacion=1,1&formatoHorizontal=false&metadatosWeb=true&series=SI744&formatoXLS.y=10
with it I can get an Excel file with this table: [MME Prices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbe5Z.png)
I tried to use `urlread`,`webread` and `readtable` but they are not getting the data. `webread` gives this output: [webread's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO1EM.png)
How could I get the data properly?
I'm using matlab 2021a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the function urlwrite and readtable in combination should works.

Example.

```
url = 'https://www.banxico.org.mx/SieInternet/consultarDirectorioInternetAction.do?accion=consultarSeries&locale=es&version=3&anoInicial=1996&anoFinal=2099&tipoInformacion=1,1&formatoHorizontal=false&metadatosWeb=true&series=SI744&formatoXLS.y=10';
fileName = 'file.xlsx';
urlwrite(url, fileName);
T = readtable(fileName,'Range','A18:B40');
```